# How do I add GUI elements in MFC in VC++ and then use the user inputted values?

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, mdi

How do I design a GUI (Multiple Document Interface) in VC++ using MFC which can take two input parameters from users and then prompt the user for entering user name and password and then use these details for later usage in the program?
This has to be done in Visual Studio 2015.
I couldn't find any proper help on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you have any mocks please do share so that it would help us understand better your requirement.

Please refer to this for a quick intro:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx

The basic idea is you create dialogs for your application and the code behind class of your dialog will store the data in your case the user entered parameters.

In case you are new to MFC I would suggest writing a dialog based sample initially and then pick up on the MDI and SDI applications.

In case have some other confusins let me know